# change name of a service file when creating a package

Tags: packaging, deb, debian, systemd

How can I create a service with a name different from the name of the package?

I'm preparing a package that provides also a service file (systemd config) that should have a name different from the package.

Currently I added a file debian/pkg_name.service and it works but the name does not reflect the service started.

I already noticed that `dh_installinit` has a `--name` option but tha man page lists

> debian/package.name.init, debian/package.name.default and
>   debian/package.name.upstart instead of the usual debian/package.init,
>              debian/package.default and debian/package.upstart

but not package.service. Moreover I haven't really understood where I should place the line. Currently my debian/rules has

```
%:
        dh  $@ --with bash-completion --with systemd
```

Comment: I don't see a clearly defined question here

Comment: See the `--name` option of [`dh_installinit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dh_installinit.1.html).

Comment: What? Does the manpage have to exhaustively list examples? As for where you should place the line, see https://joeyh.name/blog/entry/debhelper_dh_overrides/

Comment: I thought ot was limiting to named examples... So I changed my debian/rules as follows:

`%:
 dh  $@ --with bash-completion --with systemd --with python2

override_dh_installinit:
 dh_installinit -p thunder-buildout-prod --name oooctl.service
`

But I get an error I can't really understand:

Use of uninitialized value $filename in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debian/Debhelper/Dh_Lib.pm line 410.

I get this error even if I use an absolute path

Comment: I'm conviced that *.service file are not hadled by dh_installinit, they're not listed in man page and I've not been able to find a solution with it. See below for my answer.

Answer (score 1):

At last I solved it with the following configuration:

1. package name is  thunder-buildout-prod
2. debian/oooctl.service as in question
3. in debian/rules:

> ```
> %:
>   dh  $@ --with bash-completion --with systemd --with python2
>
> override_dh_systemd_enable:
>   dh_systemd_enable -p thunder-buildout-prod debian/oooctl.service
>
> override_dh_systemd_start:
>   dh_systemd_start -p thunder-buildout-prod debian/oooctl.service
> ```

As a last note. Having a script in /etc/init.d/oooctl (note: same name as the service) that sources  /lib/lsb/init-functions, this is enought to make it just work as a call to systemctl start/stop/status oooctl.service ignoring the rest of the script

Comment: (no "t" at the end of "enough")

Answer (score 1):

According to the `dh_systemd_enable` manual https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/dh_systemd_enable.1.en.html:

```
--name=name
    Install the service file as name.service instead of the default 
    filename, which is the package.service. When this parameter is 
    used, dh_systemd_enable looks for and installs files named 
    debian/package.name.service instead of the usual debian/package.service.
```

I found that you also need to pass the name to `dh_installinit`. For example, if your package was amed "mytool" but you want your service file to be `mytoolsrv.service` instead of `mytool.service`, you would create the file `debian/tool.toolsrv.service` and put the following in you `debian/rules` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@

override_dh_systemd_enable:
    dh_systemd_enable --name=mytoolsrv

override_dh_installinit:
    dh_installinit --name=mytoolsrv
```

Tested with `debhelper` compatibility level 10.